# Configuring Keycloak v15 with Postgresql v13

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, keycloak, datasource

I followed the steps mentioned here to configure Keycloak 15.0.0 with PostgreSQL 13.

1. I have created a folder inside
   (keycloak-15.0.0\modules\system\layers\keycloak\org -->
   \postgresql\main) and pasted postgresql-42.2.23 jar and added
   module.xml.
2. I have updated my standalone.xml file with changes for
   driver and datasource connection properties.

But when I give the command standalone.bat -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100, it is failing due to

Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: datasources/KeycloakDS [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException]

and Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException. If anyone faced the same issue and resolve it?

Comment: You should look the previous error why `datasources/KeycloakDS` is not created.

Answer (score 0):

I have completely cleared the folder (keycloak - unzipped) and followed the same steps mentioned above, it is working fine now.